# Envers audit entities

Tags: hibernate-envers

What is the better way to get list of audited entites?
It is possible to use REVCHANGES table and look up all audited entytoes from this table but I belive that this is not best solution.

Thanks,
Volodymyr

Comment: List of audited entities, in what sense?

Comment: I mean list of entities that currently audited in the system. 
As example when @Audited annotation is added to entity All logs will be written into Entity_Name_AUD table by default. This behaviour could be easily changed. And the question is what is the better way to get list of entitites that currently Audited in the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Hibernate's Configuration object, you can call AuditConfiguration.getFor(cfg), and then the EntitiesConfigurations object to check if an entity is audited or not.

Note though that this is not an official API.